# CI and MSBuild adding EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration

(I am still a beginner with this stuff) So I am implementing CI with Jenkins which builds using MSBUild. Pulling the code and building with Visual Studio works, but when I pull from the repo (bitbucket) I get these sort of errors:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
>   make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation errors.
>   [C:\Users\bob.jenkins\workspace\sift\source\SIFT.Model\SIFT.Model.csproj]

and because of that I get these sort of errors

> Domain\Incident.cs(5,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\Users\bob.jenkins\workspace\sift\source\SIFT.Model\SIFT.Model.csproj]

Now I know it has something to do with the repo not allowing dll or other kinds of files (we don't want it to because it messes with other peoples builds). And I don't want to just copy paste or download it onto the CI server because that would defeat our purpose of checking the build. So my question is, is there anyway for Jenkins or MSBuild to somehow grab and install EntityFramework online so we get no errors when it builds? From what I saw Visual Studio doing it looks likes it uses npm and NuGet.

Comment: Before compiling restore the Nuget packages of the solution.

Comment: https://automatetheplanet.com/integrate-jenkins-msbuild-nuget/

Comment: I had no idea it was that simple - I thought NuGet had a completely different use. Thanks @SteveGreene!